# Angular 8 error '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm new to Angular 8 and I am using the following structure to fetch data from http get and I am trying to iterate data using *ngFor. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error.

How to fix the error? Thank you in advance 

`'[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

student model

```
export class Student {
    Name: string;
    Sport: string;

}
```

student.service.ts

```
    public getData(path: string): Observable<Student[]> {
        return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.mainUrl + path).pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log('fetched data'))
        );
    }
```

student.component.ts

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { Student } from 'src/app/models/student';
import { HttpService } from 'src/services/http.service';
import { StudentService } from './student.service';


@Component ({
    selector: 'student',
    templateUrl: 'student.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['student.component.css']
})

export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
    students: Student[];

    constructor(
        private studentService: StudentService
        ) {
    }

    getStudents(): void {

        let ppp = this.studentService.getData("get_students");
        this.studentService.getData("get_students").subscribe(
            students => { this.students = students }
            // students => {console.log(this.students)}
        );
        console.log(this.students); // prints undefined
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getStudents();

    }   
}
```

student.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let p of students">

  <div>hello</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data returned by `this.studentService.getData("get_students")` is an array? The error messages suggests it is actually an object.

Comment: @UncleDave yes, because `students => {console.log(this.students)}` will show the json array

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server response is an object you need to retrieve server response data from it

```
public getData(path: string): Observable<Student[]> {
  return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.mainUrl + path).pipe(
    map(({ student }) => student)
  );
}
```

That should work if your server sends actual array if it still keeps complaining you need to convert that response into an array.